# Automorphism group any bounded domain of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, lie-groups, complex-geometry

So far the automorphism group I have calculated for known domain is a Lie Group,so  Automorphism group any bounded domain of $\mathbb{C}$ is a lie group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a 1935 result of Henri Cartan that the automorphism group $Aut(D)$ of a bounded domain  $D\subset \mathbb C^n$ is a real Lie group.
Also, the holomorphic automorphism group of any Riemann surface is a real Lie group.
Each of these two results solves your problem but unfortunately there does not seem to be a book on holomorphic functions of one variable proving the particular case you are interested in.

In the same vein (but not directly relevant to your question), the holomorphic automorphisms of a compact manifold form a real Lie group, according to a theorem of Bochner and Montgomery.

A great specialist, W. Kaup, has written [a survey  article](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dspace.rice.edu%2Fbitstream%2Fhandle%2F1911%2F63006%2Farticle_RIP562_part16.pdf%3Fsequence%3D1&ei=DBM6UePBE6SO7AaL3oHwAg&usg=AFQjCNGPOwcv2krO-7Ww5wFhjfwTIp5yHg&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU) on all these results, which will also allow you to access the bibliography of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Every complex automorphism is an isometry in the hyperbolic metric, and, conversely, an isometry in hyperbolic metric is either holomorphic or antiholomorphic automorphism of the domain. The isometry group is a Lie group by the [Myers-Steenrod theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Steenrod_theorem). Holomorphic automorphisms form a closed subgroup (of index 2), hence a Lie group of its own.

Comment: reference for study? I dont know riemannian Geometry, hyp geometric etc, only basic complan and diff geom

Comment: @CityOfGod  Chapter 2 of "Teichmüller spaces" by Hubbard gives a readable exposition of hyperbolic metric on planar domains (Chapter 3 then moves to surfaces). You don't  need much Riemannian geometry here: the metric is defined by $|dz|/(1-|z|^2)$ on the unit disk, and pushed from the disk to other domains by a covering map (one has to check that "pushing" is well-defined).

Comment: I +1'd your answer if only because I didn't know that the fact that the isometry group is a Lie group is a deep theorem due to Steenrod. :) Could you please explain why every complex automorphism is an isometry in the hyperbolic metric? I only knew this result for simply-connected domains (unequal to $\mathbb{C}$), since such domains are biholomorphic to $H^{+}$ by Riemann mapping.

Comment: @PiotrPstragowski Continuing my explanation from previous comment: consider  holomorphic covering map from the disk to the domain. This is a local isometry. Automorphisms of the domain lift to Moebius maps on the disk, which preserve the metric.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your argument now. How does one construct this covering map? Is this some "weak" form of Uniformization theorem? The proof of Riemann mapping that I know goes the other way around - it constructs a map from the domain to the disk.

Comment: @PiotrPstragowski Indeed, this is a special case of uniformization of Riemann surfaces. I don't know if it has a much easier proof  than the general case. By the way, the variational  proof of Riemann mapping theorem that I was taught went from the disk to the domain, by maximizing $|f'(0)|$ among such holomorphic injective maps. I never learned if this variational approach works for the general case.